# Exchange Online Powershell Dynamic Dist. List of Contacts

Tags: exchange, powershell, microsoft-office-365, exchangeonline

We have Exchange online with Office 365.  I am trying to set up a dynamic distribution list of **external** mail contacts if their address contains a certain email domain.  I have tried the powershell script below (as well as the WindowsEmailAddress and EmailAddresses attributes instead of External) but can not get it to work.  Anyone know how I could accomplish this?  With Exchange Online, it has to be done in Powershell.

`Set-DynamicDistributionGroup -Identity "Test Group" -RecipientFilter {((RecipientType -eq 'MailContact') -and -(ExternalEmailAddress -like '@example.com'))}`

From what I can tell, the email address filter doesn't seem to be working.  The domain is definitely correct.  Is there an attribute that can check email addresses for Mail Contacts?

Comment: There is a "-" in front of "(ExternalEmailAddress [...]" that needs to be removed. When using `-like` you have to use a wildcard character. Please try `ExternalEmailAddress -like '*@example.com'`

Comment: I get "Wildcards cannot be used as the first character. Please revise the filter criteria."

Comment: This is absolutely wild that it is 2022 and the wildcards issue is still here.  What is Microsoft even doing?

Answer (score 0):

I have resorted to using the Company attribute and doing this:

```
Set-DynamicDistributionGroup -Identity "Test Group" -RecipientFilter     
{((RecipientType -eq 'MailContact') -and (Company -eq 'Example'))}.
```

Will be one extra step per person but since that other filter has been so much trouble I'm fine with it.